# Como acessar arquivos da hospedagem pelo Windows Explorer

Tags: ftp, cpanel

Possuo um site hospedado e gostaria de gerenciar os arquivos pelo Windows Explorer da mesma forma que faço pelo Cpanel, é possível fazer isso?

Se sim, alguma dica de como fazê-lo?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Essencialmente não pode de forma normal. Isto seria possível em uma hospedagem que possua alguma forma de comunicação entre os servidores, algo como o [SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block), por exemplo, mas você só conseguiria em um servidor seu, em hospedagem compartilhada ninguém permitirá.

O que dá para fazer é usar o Windows Explorer como um cliente de FTP. Não recomendo, a experiência é ruim, mas é possível acessar seu servidor, se tiver uma conta FTP habilitada através do endereço `ftp://usuario@servidor`, vai pedir a senha. Como não pode configurar nada pode não funcionar em certas situações. Não pode várias contas no mesmo servidor lembrando senha.

[image: FTP Windows Explorer]